# How to store different cookies for different controls in GeckoFX

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies, gecko, geckofx

I am able to delete all cookies by this code:

```
nsICookieManager CookieMan;

CookieMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1");
CookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>(CookieMan);
CookieMan.RemoveAll();
```

But there is a problem. For an example, I have 2 gecoWebBrowser controls in my form. Let me call the first one as gecko1 and second one as gecko2.

gecko1 navigated to gmail and logged to it. When gecko2 navigates gmail, bingo! it's already logged too! 
When I clear cookies by using code as shown above, both of them sign outs from gmail.
Need help here, how can I store different cookies for different controls?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to have different cookie containers for two different GeckoFX controls in the same application. This is because the profile directory (where cookies are saved) is shared.

You can solve this by having two applications running separately with one control each and two different profile directories.

Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614986/2440