# GeckoFX 45 separate instances

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

I need GeckoFX C# browsers to act separately inside one Form -- each control instance should have its own:

- cookies,
- cache,
- proxy settings

etc.

Is this possible to achieve and how?

Comment: Hey - this might be pretty hard - I implemented such behaviour by invoking separate app instances. 
See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042354/how-to-set-different-proxies-for-each-geckofx-instance
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212262/how-to-make-gecko-use-seperate-cookiecontainer-per-instance?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I see, I had a hope they've implemented such feature since those questions; what kind of invoke communication have you used? I was thinking about pipes, but that doesn't look really like a modern .NET approach, or is it?

Comment: I didn't require any communication between the instances, so it was enough for me to do a process.start() with some arguments.

Comment: I have no idea. Honestly I know the MS web browser control can't do it since they all have the same WinInet Cache. I know a few versions of firefox used the internet security settings from IE, but that is something you will have to test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Gecko use seperate CookieContainer per instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212262/how-to-make-gecko-use-seperate-cookiecontainer-per-instance)